# difference GMM with trending variables

Tags: trend, generalized-moments, differences

I want to estimate a panel equation of the form
$$
y_{it}=ρ y_{i,t−1}+β_1 x_{1,t}+⋯+β_k x_{k,t}+ c_i+γ_t+ϵ_{it}
$$
where $c_i$ are country specific effects, $γ_t$ period effects  and $ϵ_{it}$ error term.

the problem is that some of individual time series have certain trend, but the first difference of the variables are stationary

Can I perform difference GMM estimation proposed by Arellano-Bond(1991) on this equation given the fact that it performs first difference transformation or I need stationarity in levels in order to proceed to estimation?

Answer (score 1):

If levels are not stationary, you can use differences as instruments. [It is explained in this topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112431/unit-roots-and-gmm-estimation).

> In this case you're moment conditions might be $E[\Delta\epsilon_{it}
> y_{it-1}]=0$. This instrument relies on some correlation between
>   $y_{it}$ and $\Delta y_{it}$ to avoid the weak instruments problem.
>   However, $\Delta y_{it}$ can be written as: $$ \Delta y_{it} = (\rho -
> 1) y_{i,t-1}+c_i+\epsilon_t$$
>
> If your series is near stationary, then $\rho$ will be near 1 and your
>   instruments will be very weak. Moreover, if the correlation between
>   $y_{i,t-1}$ and $c_i$ is positive, then your estimate of $\rho$ will
>   be biased towards one. This may suggest to you that if you have $\rho$
>   far away from one you're probably fine. However you may not know the
>   correlation of $y_{i,t}$ and $c_i$, and this problem may apply to
>   other persistent regressors - so it may be difficult to figure out
>   exactly how the bias would affect your estimates.
>   Blundell and Bond addressed the problem for near-stationary processes
>   in two articles, [Blundell and Bond (1998)](http://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/econom/v87y1998i1p115-143.html) and [Blundell and Bond
>   (1999)](http://ideas.repec.org/p/ifs/ifsewp/99-04.html). Their simple way to solve the weak instrument problem is
>   to use first differences as instruments for levels instead, $E[\Delta
> y_{i,t-1} \epsilon_{it}]=0$.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144693)

Comment: I added an extended quote from the main answer.